# Bigquery related links are not working.

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to open links related to Google Bigquery; however they are not working. Those are the links specified in lot of documents and links. It is the same link that is being referenced from Google Developers Page ( https://console.developers.google.com/project/concise-option-705/storage?authuser=0 )
I had tried opening following link:

https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/project/concise-option-705

Are these links changed or is there any other way to access Google Bigquery or Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2):

That link should work, and it does for me--at least, the UI loads and bounces me to a project that I actually have access to.

By the way, bug reports are probably best filed at BQ's public issue tracker rather than on StackOverflow.

https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/

Comment: Henceforth I would file issues on tracker. Need only one clarification needed - Am I getting this issue because account that I am using is not a premium account?

Comment: Nope. Any account should work. But if you're still seeing errors, please send us some details!

Comment: When we tried opening https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/project/concise-option-705 URL, we are getting error message as "This webpage is not available" . Detailed Message - "The webpage at https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/project/concise-option-705 might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
Error code: ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED"

We are using this link through company's proxy server.
Let us know if any further details are required.

Comment: Sounds like it's probably an issue with the proxy. I'd chat with the admins at your company to see if they have any suggestions.